# Getting post revision and printing them on the post content site

Tags: wp-query, wpdb, revisions

I trying to print older post revisions on the content.php site (theme: twentytwenty), and this, with staticly set value works..

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'revision' AND post_parent = '6'");
```

But if I wanted this dynamically for each post it prints me only ID of post and nothing more..
That magic piece of content.php:

```
<?php
  $post_id = the_ID();
  
  global $wpdb;
  //$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'revision' AND post_parent = '. $post_id.';");
  $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'revision' AND post_parent = '%d'", $post_id);
  $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
  foreach($results as $row) {
    echo '<h6 class="max-percentage" style="text-align:center;">Verze článku z: '.$row->post_date.'<br></h6>';
    echo $row->post_content.'<br>';
  } 
  ?>
```

I also tried lot of ways what I search on google but no one works for me..
Any tips?

Comment: What do you mean "throwing them"?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I mean printing on the post site with "throwing them".